# How to replace conjunct consonants with underscore/macrons below letters

Tags: firefox

I like to replace first or first and second consonant in conjunct consonants with a underlined consonant in roman transliterated text of Indic language.

for example
kiss bulk hind pyaar kyaa kranti  mukhya inglish tren drive patni buddha  >>>>>

kis̠s bul̠k hin̠d  p̠yaar k̠ranti muk̠ya in̠g̠lish 
t̠ren d̠rive pat̠ni bud̠dha

Please correct my **guessed** Regular Expression.

Replace 
([bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyz]h?)([bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyz]h?

with
$1$2

I have typed macrons below letters here. They may or may not be unicode macrons.
b̠c̠d̠f̠g̠h̠j̠k̠l̠m̠n̠p̠r̠s̠t̠v̠w̠x̠y̠z̠
http://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/phonetic.htm

Comment: Please, use code markdown for formatting patterns and snippets

Comment: Here is a link. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/foxreplace/

Comment: Here is a link. Please rewrite the above expression.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/foxreplace/